# Automating provisioning of mail boxes in Lotus Notes using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Has anyone done this?

What apis/approaches were used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can certainly be done and there are a number of companies selling solutions.  IBM Tivoli can do it as can [HDSL FiRM](http://www.hadsl.com/).

As for writing it yourself, I've not done it, but the easiest way will probably be to create documents in the Administration Requests Database (ADMIN4.nsf) and let the AdminP process do the heavy lifting.  This is basically what happens when you do it manually anyway.  Try starting by looking at what documents get created when you register a new user.  This will give you a template to follow when creating them programmatically.